# Webcat: Access Denied by Content Filter

Tags: categories, access-denied

I was informed that my website was blocked on the screen of a user. Message he got is:

> Access Denied by Content Filter
>
> Based on our organization's access policies, access to this web site
>   (http://www.example.com/) has been blocked because of the web category
>   "Uncategorized URLs" is not allowed.
>
> For asssistance, please contact the IT Help desk......

Further details about the error message contain:

> Category: Uncatgorized URLs 
>   Reason: BLOCK-WEBCAT 
>   Notification: WEBCAT

Having checked our Websites category based on Cyberoam's website (http://www.cyberoamsecuritycenter.com/cyberoamsupport/webpages/webcat/webcathome.jsp) I was informed that the website is categorized as 'BusinessAndEconomy'. A proper conclusion based on the content of our website.

My question now is: Is a BLOCK-WEBCAT error message always based on information about website categories stored in Cyberoam's database? Or do other organisations have website category indexes that are being used for internet filters too?

Comment: check firewall, add domain as trusted, check iis MIME types, check ASP.NET, IIS_User permissions on website folder....

Comment: It sounds like it is actually saying that the URL isn't categorized: `Category: Uncategorized URLs` which means you may have a blanket filter blocking anything without a category.